# WCF trust client certificates only from one root ca

Tags: wcf, https, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate, client-certificates

When securing WCF services with server and client certificates there is an easy way to ensure the identity of the service provider certificate (server certificate), by comparing the public key or finger print of the sender certificate with an expected value.

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx this is explained in step 8. You can config your app.config file in the endpoint section with an identity element where you can pass in the expected encoded finger print value of the server certificate. A comparison between received service certificate and expected value ensures I am talking to the server I expect.

But now I consider the servers point of view. The server can have several RootCA certificates in its certificate store. If the client certificate send from the requester was issued (and signed) by one of these RootCA my service will trust this client certificate. How can I ensure that my service will only trust certificates issued by one determined RootCA? And how can I configure the one trusted RootCA?

(I think this could be some kind of an equivalent way of certificate pinning for client certificates issued by on RootCA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this would be to roll your own custom x509 certificate validator.  Then for each incoming request you can simply check to make sure the client certificate was issued by your root CA.  It's actually quite easy to do.  You can find the steps to implement this here:

[How to: Create a Service that Employs a Custom Certificate Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Scott Thornton
This works for me. In this way I am able the reject all unwanted certificates (certificat issuer) and validate the owner of the certificate (certificate subject)